# XSLT with lot's of WHEN's which are different per company. How to manage?

Tags: xslt

I have an xslt file that converts a Peppol xml vendor invoice to an an xml that can be imported into our ERP-system. The xml that is imported has the same layout for every administration, therefore the xslt can be applied for each administration as well. However, the xslt contains long lists (many vendors) to include vendornrs and other parameters that are vendor dependent. The vendor lists in the xslt are different per administration (we have about 10 administrations/companies, each has around 100 vendors from which we import the invoices in xml).

```
<xsl:variable name="VendorShortName">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="cac:PartyName/cbc:Name = 'SuperVendor'">SuperV</xsl:when>
....
....
<xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="cbc:Name"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>                                                            
    
<SupplierAccountNum> 
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="cbc:Name = 'SuperVendor'">20220</xsl:when>
....
....
<xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</SupplierAccountNum>
```

In the future I would like to generate the xslt dynamically with SQL and include the source information in our ERP system but for the moment I havee to manage these lists manually.

Ideally I would like to put these lists in different documents and include these documents/lists depending on the administration (=company) name. That make it easier to manage manually.

Is there some kind of best practice on how to manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed quite straightforward to keep auxiliary data like this in external XML files, and have your XSLT load the appropriate XML at runtime, and use it to look things up.

For example, you might decide to have a separate lookup file for each vendor, and load it by name, if your input document provides you with a suitable name. Following your example, here's a file called `SuperVendor.xml`:

```
<vendor>
   <shortName>SuperV</shortName>
   <accountNum>20220</accountNum>
</vendor>
```

In your XSLT you could then load this file dynamically:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="vendor-file" select="concat(/cac:PartyName/cbc:Name, '.xml')">
<xsl:variable name="vendor-data" select="document($vendor-file)/vendor"/>
```

Then you can just use that lookup data anywhere in your XSLT...

```xml
<SupplierAccountNum><xsl:value-of select="$vendor-data/accountNum"/></supplierAccountNum>
```

If it's more convenient to manage that way, you could also read from a single XML file which contained all the vendor data, more like this:

```
<vendors>
   <vendor>
      <name>SuperVendor</name>
      <shortName>SuperV</shortName>
      <accountNum>20220</accountNum>
   </vendor>
   ...
</vendors>
```

... and load it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="current-vendor-name" select="/cac:PartyName/cbc:Name"/>
<xsl:variable name="vendor-data" 
   select="document('vendors.xml')/vendors/vendor[name=$current-vendor-name]"/>
```

Comment: Hi Conal, thank you very much, this is very usefull and very understandable. Much appreciated! It is also very smart to put the vendor masterdata in an xml file. It is also much easier to generate such a file dynamically with SQL.

Comment: Dear Conal, the variable vendor-data has all the values in it for that vendor which is nice but how do I refer to each individual value?

Comment: If you have a variable `<xsl:variable name="vendor-data" select="document($vendor-file)/vendor"/>`, the content of the variable is the `vendor` (root) element of that vendor file. You can refer to values contained in that `vendor` element by referring to that variable and appending an XPath that navigates to the particular element, text node, or attribute you want to read. e.g. `$vendor-data/shortName`, `$vendor-data/accountNum`, etc. See the third code block in my answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks, that is working perfectly. I was not aware of that. I have been searching on "variable multiple nodes" and reading posts for hours but just could not find it.

Comment: Yes, you can treat nodes in the "external" document exactly like nodes in the "source" document that you are transforming, including applying templates to them, and everything. The expression `/*` refers to the root element of your "source" document, and the expression `document('some-document.xml')/*` simply refers to the root element of the file with that name.